# Preguntas sobre !, Number y un poco de logica

Tags: javascript, if, operador-de-conversión

Buenas soy nuevo en JS, unas preguntas de logica=>
Alguien me podria explicar porque estas 3 opciones que tengo comentadas arriba entra en la primera seccion del else if: *'Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.'*
Alguien me puede decir si estoy en lo correcto en los primeros 3 comentarios esque me es un poco confuso. Gracias

```js
//Number(numeroUsuario ==='0')  => convierte 0 en 1 y por eso entra xq 1 es true? No deberia ir a impar?
//Number(numeroUsuario) === 0   => convierte a numero el string y si es igual a 0 entra al bloque
//!Number(numeroUsuario)       => // El '0' lo convierto en 0 que es false by default y lo niego con ! por lo que ahora es true y por eso entra

let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');
  if (numeroUsuario === null) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.');
  } else if(Number(numeroUsuario) === 0 || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '') {
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
  } else {
    if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
      modulo = 'par';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    } else {
      modulo = 'impar';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En una pregunta anterior ya te expliqué que ese código no es un buen ejemplo para seguir, pero en cualquier te resuelvo las dudas:

`Number(valor)` intenta obtener un número en función de lo que le pases.

En el caso de los valores booleanos, true es 1 y false es 0:

```js
console.log(Number(false));
console.log(Number(true));
```

Por tanto, `Number(numeroUsuario ==='0')` será 1 si se cumple que `numeroUsuario` es exactamente un string con el caracter 0.

En el caso de que pasemos un string, `Number` intenta leer los caracteres numéricos. Si lo consigue, devolverá el número encontrado. En otro caso devolverá NaN (Not a Number). Un caso especial es la cadena vacía, que devuelve 0:

```js
console.log(Number('012'));
console.log(Number(''));
console.log(Number('hola'));
```

Por tanto `Number(numeroUsuario) === 0` será `true` siempre que `numeroUsuario` sea `'0'` o `''`

Y por último, negar un número nos devuelve `true` si el número es 0 y `false` en cualquier otro caso:

```js
console.log(!0);
console.log(!123);
console.log(!1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque está entrando en el if `Number(numeroUsuario) === 0` que devuelve `true`, deberías eliminar esa comprobación porque comprueba si `0 === 0`.

Otra forma de resolver lo que estás intentando de hacer es así:

```
let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');
  // valida que no sea null o vacío
  if (numeroUsuario === null || !numeroUsuario.length) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.');
    // utilizo "continue" para cortar el ciclo del for
    // y continuar con el siguiente
    continue;
  }
  // si no es un número
  if (isNaN(numeroUsuario)) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
    continue;
  }

  // validacion de par o impar
  if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
    modulo = 'par';
  } else {
    modulo = 'impar';
  }

  alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
}
```